# Create object name and value in changeHandler

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an object using the field as the property and the value as the value.

```
  onChange(e) {
    const field = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const selectedData = { field, value };
    this.props.dispatch(updateForm({ selectedData }));
  }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this using `bracket` notation.

```
 let selectedData = {[field]: value};
```

Short example:

```js
let field="number";
let value=10;
const selectedData = {[field]: value};
console.log(selectedData);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const selectedData = {};
selectedData[field] = value;
```

Comment: Or, additionally, you could: const selectedData = { "field" : value };

Comment: @sapit - That's not the same at all. Your thing is the equivalent of `const selectedData = { field: value }`, the quotes are optional in Javascript. (As opposed to JSON.)

Comment: @sapit, you can use bracket notation : `[field]` like in my answer.

Comment: I stand corrected, my bad! Apologies.